# All combinations of substrings that can be concatenated into the original string in R

Tags: r, string, substring, combinatorics

Given a set of n unique ordered characters,

How can I find all combinations of substrings that can be concatenated into the original set of ordered characters (in R)?

For example, for n=5, using alphabetical characters starting with a, the input (as a character element) and desired output (as a list of vectors of character elements) would be as follows,

Input:

```
ordered.chars <- "abcde"
```

Desired output:

```
ord.substr.list <- list(
c("a","b","c","d","e"),
c("ab","c","d","e"),
c("ab","cd","e"),
c("ab","c","de"),
c("a","bc","d","e"),
c("a","bc","de"),
c("a","b","cd","e"),
c("a","b","c","de"),
c("abc","d","e"),
c("abc","de"),
c("a","bcd","e"),
c("a","b","cde"),
c("ab","cde"),
c("abcd","e"),
c("a","bcde"))
```

A test of the condition that all listed vectors of character elements concatenate into the original character element:

```
all(unlist(lapply(ord.substr.list, function(x) paste(x, collapse=""))) %in% ordered.chars)
```

My google/stackoverflow searches lead to combn(), which is useful in similar cases, but does not seem to be obviously helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the heart of your problem is being able to generate the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Here is a solution using `RcppAlgos` (I am the author).

```
library(RcppAlgos)

customPowSetStr <- function(n) {
    len <- n * 2 - 1
    v <- vector("character", length = len)
    v[seq(1, len, 2)] <- letters[1:n]
    v[seq(2, len, 2)] <- ","

    comboGeneral(0:(n - 1), n - 1, freqs = c(n - 2, rep(1, n - 1)), FUN = function(x) {
        temp <- v
        strsplit(paste0(temp[-(x[x > 0] * 2)], collapse = ""), ",")[[1]]
    })
}

customPowSetStr(5)
[[1]]
[1] "ab" "c"  "d"  "e" 

[[2]]
[1] "a"  "bc" "d"  "e" 

[[3]]
[1] "a"  "b"  "cd" "e" 

[[4]]
[1] "a"  "b"  "c"  "de"

[[5]]
[1] "abc" "d"   "e"  

[[6]]
[1] "ab" "cd" "e" 

[[7]]
[1] "ab" "c"  "de"

[[8]]
[1] "a"   "bcd" "e"  

[[9]]
[1] "a"  "bc" "de"

[[10]]
[1] "a"   "b"   "cde"

[[11]]
[1] "abcd" "e"   

[[12]]
[1] "abc" "de" 

[[13]]
[1] "ab"  "cde"

[[14]]
[1] "a"    "bcde"

[[15]]
[1] "abcde"
```

Comment: That is a very succinct solution! Great link about power sets as well. I was hoping that there were some interesting theoretical aspects of creating this data, and I am not leaving disappointed.